# How to pass a variable from a function to a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I print path outside function:

```
class FirstClas:

    path = ''
    def num(self):
        path = "C:\\Users\\JOHN\\Desktop\\test.txt"
        return path

    print(path)
```

This method don't print anything.

This result:

```
C:\Python\python.exe C:/Users/JOHN/Desktop/test/tt.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance from the class that you created.

I would suggest doing this:

```
test = FirstClas()
print(test.num())
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Your method never gets called, and the class variable `path` is pointless here.  Do:

```
class FirstClas:

    def num(self):
        path = "C:\\Users\\JOHN\\Desktop\\test.txt"
        return path


print(FirstClas().num())  # note that this is outside the class!
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you quite understand the purpose of classes, but here's how to make what you have "work" (in the sense that there are no fatal errors):

File **`global_variable.py`**

```
def init_global_variable():
    """initialize variable"""
    global GLOBALS_DICT
    GLOBALS_DICT = {}


def set_variable(name, value):
    """set variable"""
    try:
        GLOBALS_DICT[name] = value
        return True
    except KeyError:
        return False


def get_variable(name):
    """get variable"""
    try:
        return GLOBALS_DICT[name]
    except KeyError:
        return "Not Found"


init_global_variable()  # ADDED.
```

File **`tt.py`**

```
import os
#import lib.global_variable as glv
import global_variable as glv  # Since I don't have your whole package.


class FirstClas:

    def num(self):
        path = "C:\\Users\\JOHN\\Desktop\\test.txt"
        return path

    def imag(self):
        icon_file = os.path.join(
            glv.get_variable("APP_PATH"),
            glv.get_variable("DATA_DIR"),
            "paths",
            "PathExcel",
        )
        return icon_file

class Second:

    # Put statements in a method so they don't run when the class is defined.
    def run(self):
        test = FirstClas()
        print('first: ' + test.num())
        print('second: ' + test.imag())

second = Second()
second.run()
```

Output:

```
first: C:\Users\JOHN\Desktop\test.txt
second: Not Found\Not Found\paths\PathExcel
```

Comment: this code `init_global_variable()` important in module `global_variable.py` , I run script without using it and work fine, I have script need function like that `print('first: ' + test.num())`  without using `def run(self):` , because I pass it to another module, if the method possible or not

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you create an _instance_ of the `FirstClas` class, like `test` in the `run()` method, you can then either pass `test` to the other module, or even `test.run` (i.e. without `()` suffix) because functions and methods are also objects in Python.

Comment: Also, you don't really need the `init_global_variable()` function, because you can cause the global variable to automatically be created when the submodule is imported by putting a `GLOBALS_DICT = {}` at the beginning of the `global_variable.py` file.

Comment: but why? , I get Not Found in this line, second: Not Found\Not Found\paths\PathExcel. this script not Found the path of PathExcel after run.

Comment: You're getting Not Found because the `GLOBALS_DICT` is empty.

Comment: Ho to fix it to get full path without messing anything , this is example print from another module by same code but all is same function: C:/Users/JOHN/Desktop/test\data\image\inter.jpg

Comment: I have no idea. Note these are **classes** not functions, so it's still unclear to me what exactly you're trying to accomplish — sorry.

Comment: can you see this post, this is what I trying to accomplish: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61902715/pythone-pass-return-from-method-or-class-to-another-class-to-run-in-pyinstalle

Comment: Something needs to call `set_variable()` and put values into `GLOBALS_DICT` after it's initialized to the empty dictionary `{}` — that must be done somewhere because it will not automatically happen.

Comment: I don't know ho to edit it. can you edit this code for me?

Comment: I use same code and work fine: `    def image(self):
        icon_file = os.path.join(
            glv.get_variable("APP_PATH"),
            glv.get_variable("DATA_DIR"),
            "image",
            "icon.ico",
        )
        self.iconbitmap(icon_file)` .

This is Output: C:/Users/JOHN/Desktop/test\data\image\icon.ico

Comment: I don't know where to put it, but the code to put the values into `GLOBALS_DICT` would need to be something like `glv.set_variable("APP_PATH", <desired value>)` and `glv.set_variable("DATA_DIR", <desired value>)`.

Answer (score 0):

the path does not changed(path = ' ') because you don't run the function num